# Upload a file from Excel to Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, upload

I am trying to upload a xls file onto a website using VBA from Excel.

I managed to open the website and got to the stage where you click on "Browse..." to choose the file to upload.

I get the error

> "Object variable of with block variable not set"

The code is below, as is the html element.

```
'input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="fileUpload" style="height:20px;width:450px;"

Sub Upload()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium

    IE.Visible = 1
    With IE

        .Navigate url

        Do While (IE.Busy Or IE.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
            DoEvents
        Loop            

        ' Selects Create Report
        .Document.getElementById("ctl00_body_upload").Click
        .Document.getElementById("FileUpload").Click ' <<<This is where it fails

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End With

    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you giving it enough time to load? Try adding  `Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")` before `.Document.getElementById("FileUpload").Click` and see if you get the same error.